# Ubuntu Terminal C++ program being called in other program stuck, even though they separately work fine

Tags: c++, ubuntu, wrapper

Long story short:

I created a program to get the path to a model file, do something with that information and pass on a different set of information, then i tried to create a wrapper for another program that basically catches the command line arguments and funnels some of them to my program to do its thing.

Simplified program flow.

Software --> args[all] --> Wrapper --> args[some] --> Program --> Output

The problem i now have is, calling my program on its own with hard-coded information or command line arguments equal to what the Wrapper would pass on works both flawlessly. The same goes for the Wrapper it works independently.

It also works to have the Wrapper pass on arguments and call the Program if the model information is wrong, which results in a simple string warning. But if the path to the model is correct it gets stuck in an endless loop and i don't know why. Separate runtimes are 8-11s for the Program and maybe 2s for the Wrapper, but i let it run for about 10min and nothing happened after some dummy print code.

Wrapper:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if(argc > 1){
    string tmp0 = argv[1];
    string tmp1 = "./program " + tmp0;
    const char* model = tmp1.c_str();

    int status = system(model);
  }
  else{
    cout << "No Model Information.\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Parameters would be: Path to a model file and some other stuff, but only the path to the model would be passed on to the program in this case.

Program:

```
#include "program.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if(argc > 1){
    string tmp = argv[1];
    const char* model = tmp.c_str();
    cout << program(model);
  }
  else{
    cout << "At least one defined Argument for the Model needs to be given.\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Program Function Pseudo Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

string program(const char* model){
  string tmp
  read(model);
  if(model has variables) do
    tmp = "has variables";
  return tmp
}
```

--- Edit ---
The program function code is in pseudo code because its too complex and specific to list here without a load of libraries and other stuff being listed. If thats necessary i can try to provide it, but as it is i dont have a small or simple example i can give.

--- End edit ---

I don't understand enough about command line arguments to write sophisticated code, so i know this is more or less shitty, but i only need to be able to execute the program from the wrapper somehow and need to be able to read and pass on specific command line arguments. This is just the best i came up with.

Executing the Program code alone, with correct model information: ~10s execution time
Executing the Program code alone, with wrong model information: ~2s execution time
Executing the Wrapper code alone: ~2s execution time
Executing the Wrapper code, calling the Program code with wrong model information: ~2s execution time
Executing the Wrapper code, calling the Program code with correct model information: endless wait

I just dont get why it doesnt progress even though each works separately.

Comment: What is the `program` function doing? Please create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Its taking the model path, loads it and then does some stuff with the information and in the end returns a string. The problem is i cant list much more code since its rather big, super specific and not easily reproducible.

Comment: You could connect a debugger to the running `program` process to see where it's stalling. Or you could add a lot of output as well to narrow it down. Or just scale back your program to the bare minimum where everything works, and then add back functionality a little piece at a time until the problem occurs, then you have narrowed it down and can add more precise debugging output around that part.

Comment: Thanks, ill try to scaling back for now, maybe its one of the sub functions that causes problems. Its just hard to understand as a newbie why it works alone but not together.

Comment: If the program uses files and opens them using relative paths, the working directory might not be what's expected when it opens those files? Do you have adequate error checking to make sure all operations that can fail doesn't actually file (opening of files, allocation of memory, etc.)?

Comment: Thats it i think. Now that you mention it i have a few relative paths to files that i open, read, save and close that wouldnt work without adjustment due to location differences. I will look into this, but i think this is it. This is a university project with a rather strict dead line and my error handling has been abysmal so sadly thats not really a good avenue :/

Comment: Lesson of the day: Never delay error handling, always include it when writing code. It will take longer to add it later. :)

Comment: It works, it was just that one file i needed a relative path for, after replacing it with an absolute it worked like a charm. Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy! Under normal circumstances i would involve more error handling but this semester has been so crazy that im just lacking everywhere in time, but i will try to keep it in mind for the future. Thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't matter how complex your second program is. You can always reduce it down to its entry point. Obviously the args from the first program are not being piped properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fork() and execvp() in the unistd.h API. Depending on the return of fork() you can have the wrapper wait or end after launching the command.
Save the source file as args.cpp and compile it with the following command:

$ g++ args.cpp -o args && ./args -l -h -a

```
#include <cstdio>                                                                                                                                                                              
#include <unistd.h>

#define SPAWNCMD "ls"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if(argc > 1)
  {
    printf("Command to spawn: %s ", SPAWNCMD); 
    
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < argc; i++)
      printf("%s ", argv[i]);

    printf("\n");

    if (fork())
      if (execvp(SPAWNCMD, argv) == -1)
      {
        printf("Incorrect termination of SPAWNCMD\n");
        return 1;
      }
  }

  else
  {
    printf("No Model Information.\n");
  }
  
  printf("Wrapper program end\n");
  return 0;
}
```